# Equation relating core and normalizer

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ and $H\leq G$, we have that
$$\text{Core}_G(H)=H\iff N_G(H)=G$$
so this lead to think if there might be some equation relating the orders or indices of the core and normalizer of $H$, such as
$$|H:\text{Core}_G(H)|=|G:N_G(H)|.$$

Quickly I realized that doesn't work, since if I'm not mistaken letting $H=A_3\leq\Sigma_n=G,n\geq 4$ we have
$$\text{Core}_G(H)=\{1\}$$
$$N_G(H)=\Sigma_3$$
but $|\Sigma_n:\Sigma_3|=n!/6\neq 3=|A_3:\{1\}|$.

Giving it extra thought I'm really not convinced of anything close to my formula since I can make that $n$ as big as I want.

However the first equivalence holds so there *is* some relation between both subgroups. Now, the question:

> is it a mere "syntactic coincidence", as in an "intersection" of both definitions that yields an equivalence in a special case but is unfruitful in the other cases, or is there an underlying relationship?

Answer (score 2):

The normalizer $N_G(H)$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ containing $H$ in which $H$ is normal. The core $\mathrm{Core}_G(H)$ is the largest subgroup of $H$ that is normal in $G$.

There *is* a connection between the two: $\mathrm{Core}_G(H)$ is the intersection of all $G$-conjugates of $H$:
$$\mathrm{Core}_G(H) = \bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}.$$
But two conjugates are equal, $xHx^{-1} = yHy^{-1}$ if and only if $y^{-1}xHx^{-1}y = H$, if and only if $y^{-1}x\in N_G(H)$, if and only if $xN_G(H) = yN_G(H)$. That is, the number of *distinct* subgroups you are intersecting in the definition of $\mathrm{Core}_G(H)$ is the index of $N_G(H)$ in $G$.

The issue is that you do not really have a lot of control over the cardinality of the intersection on the basis of how many things you are intersecting, except in *very* rough situations. If you are just intersecting one set (the case where $N_G(H)=H$) then of course you know that the intersection will have size $|H|$. But even if you have $[G:N_G(H)]=2$, you know that $\mathrm{Core}_G(H)$ will be a proper subgroup of $H$, but in principle it could have any index in $H$, not necessarily $2$. And you have even less control with, say,  $[G:N_G(H)]=3$, since it could be that two of the conjugates have the same intersection as all three. For example, a [Frobenius complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malnormal_subgroup) has the property that $H\neq \{1\}$, and for all $x\in G\setminus H$, $xHx^{-1}\cap H=\{1\}$. So there the core is trivial, and as soon as you have an intersection of two conjugates of $H$ you get the core, even though there are $[G:H]$ distinct conjugates.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{Core}_G(H)$ is the kernel (namely the intersection of all the pointwise stabilizers) of the $G$-action by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/H$, whereas $N_G(H)$ is the pointwise stabilizer of $H$ under the $G$-action by conjugation on the set of all the subgroups of $G$. As far as I know, there's no group action-theoretic connection between such two *different actions*-related objects, so I'm afraid that's more or less all.